# Fast Create in Flow Doesn't Find Any Records

Tags: visual-workflow, account-teams

I am still new to flows but I tried to re-create a flow listed [here](https://www.appcloud101.com/archives/8055) which would automatically add an account team member in a specific role to a case team. I know the issue isn't with my Process Builder since I simplified that but still no account team members are getting added to the case team.

I ran debug on my flow and the Fast Lookup and Loop seem to be working ok. Below are the results:

FAST LOOKUP: Find_Account_Team_Members
Find all AccountTeamMember records where:
AccountId Equals {!AccountIDfromPB} (001c000002UqYUWAA3)
Team_Role_Custom__c Equals Client Service Director
Store the values of these fields in Find_Account_Team_Members: Id
Result
Successfully found records.

LOOP: Loop_Through_Account_Team_Members
End Loop.

FAST CREATE: Create_Case_Team_Members
Create CaseTeamMember records using the values that are stored in {!CaseteamMembers}.
**Variable Values
None.
Result
All records are ready to be created when the next screen, pause, or local action is executed or when the interview finishes.**

How can I fix this so the case team member(s) populate? Below is a screenshot of the overall flow. Note that we are using a custom account team role field which I accounted for in the Get Records (lookup) element.

[image]

Comment: if the loop was working you would see debug for each iteration; be sure your loop is referencing the output of a record collection variable that is the result of the Get Records element

Comment: @cropredy thank you, I added that as shown here instead of setting it to "automatically store all fields": https://ibb.co/gmWm7ds.

Comment: @cropredy But now I am getting an actual error: 
FAST CREATE: Create_Case_Team_Members
Create CaseTeamMember records using the values that are stored in {!CaseteamMembers}.
Variable Values
[MemberId=005c0000006nKMBAA2,ParentId=500c000000HGwUFAA1,TeamRoleId=0B7c0000000Cdo]
Result
Failed to create records.
Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: MALFORMED_ID: Team Role ID: id value of incorrect type: 0B7c0000000Cdo. This is the ID of my Case Team role, I pulled it from the URL: [mydomain]/lightning/setup/CaseTeamRoles/page?address=%2F0B7c0000000CdoO

Comment: @cropredy it seems like Flow is dropping the last "O" from my ID?

Comment: (1) looks like a copy-paste error; (2) Flow should not use hard-coded Ids - query for the CaseTeamRole in the flow

Comment: @cropredy thank you for your help and patience! Ok, I did a Get Record for the CaseTeamRole and it looks like that is now working fine per the debug log. But now the flow can't find my Account Team member - there is absolutely one on this account's team with this role: FAST LOOKUP: Find_Account_Team_Members
Find all AccountTeamMember records where:
AccountId Equals {!AccountIDfromPB} (001c000002UqYUWAA3)
Team_Role_Custom__c Equals Client Service Director
Store those records in {!AccountTeamMembers}.
Save these field values in the variable: Id
Result
Failed to find records. Any thoughts?

Comment: @cropredy disregard, this recent issue was due to some of our customization. My flow works great now - thank you so much!

Comment: you should answer your own question and mark it as resolved - this will help the community

Answer (score 0):

Resolution was using the standard Account Team role field instead of a custom field created by our development team. In addition, needed to create a lookup to find the Case Team Role ID.